# excel - saving as csv changes format and data

Tags: excel, csv

I have a list of cells with dates in them such as:

```
17/Nov/2015
18/Nov/2015
19/Nov/2015
20/Nov/2015
```

The data inside the cells is actually as it appears to the user and the format is "text".

When I save it as a "csv", the data and format gets modified so what is displayed is:

```
17-Nov-15
18-Nov-15
19-Nov-15
20-Nov-15
```

and the actual data in the cell is:

```
11/17/2015
11/18/2015
11/19/2015
11/20/2015
```

Why is saving as a CSV modifying my cells and changing the formats and how can I stop this behavior? Thank you.

Comment: When you say *'save it as a "csv"'* don't you actually mean *'copying to Notepad and saving it'* ? If you actually saved as a xlCSV with SaveAs then the dates wouldn't change.

Comment: @Jeeped I mean I navigate to **"File" -> "Save As"** and for **"Save as type:"**, I select **CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)**

Comment: That's odd. My xl2010 does not change the custom number format (e.. dd/mmm/yyyy) when I save to CSV using SaveAs.

Comment: Just to confirm, xl2013 also does not change the format.  Are you opening the CSV file back in another instance of Excel? Because then it does change the format to the closest format that is not a custom format, and the custom format will need to be re-applied.  Or you will need to export and import the cells as text.

Comment: @ScottCraner Document was created in 2013, and updated in 2013, and I save it to a CSV in 2013. Yes I am opening the new CSV file in 2013. The format of the fields before I save as CSV is "text".